# How to compute a new variable that is defined by two variables using R?

Tags: r, merge, interaction

I have a dataset with the variables `sex` and `navigation`. The `sex` variable has `male` and `female` as values. The "navigation" variable has `menu` and `tags` as values.

I want to create a new variable with the values `male_menu`, `male_tags`, `female_menu` & `female_tags` as those are the possible combination of the two existing variables.

How can I create such a new variable in `R` and include it in the original dataset?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understood what you wanted somewhat differently than @zach. Here I use the `interaction` function to create a new factor with the four levels you specified. Here using some dummy data

```
set.seed(42)

sex <- sample(c("Male","Female"), 20, replace = TRUE)
navigation <- sample(c("menu","tags"), 20, replace = TRUE)

interaction(sex, navigation)
```

the last line gives

```
> interaction(sex, navigation)
 [1] Female.tags Female.menu Male.tags   Female.tags Female.menu Female.tags
 [7] Female.menu Male.tags   Female.menu Female.tags Male.tags   Female.tags
[13] Female.menu Male.tags   Male.menu   Female.tags Female.menu Male.menu  
[19] Male.tags   Female.tags
Levels: Female.menu Male.menu Female.tags Male.tags
```

Is that what you wanted?

Comment: After trying several options, this  'mydata$sex_org <- with(mydata,interaction(sex,navigation))'  gave the desired outcome

Comment: If you are using `with()`, to assign to the same object, consider `within` or `transform`. The equivalent calls then are: 1. `mydata <- within(mydata, sex_org <- interaction(sex,navigation))`, and 2. `mydata <- transform(mydata, sex_org = interaction(sex,navigation))`. There are differences, and `transform` is perhaps easier to use, but both work.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are creating dummy variables for a model.  Here's an easy way to do this, using `model.matrix`:

```
dat <- iris
dat$navigation <- sample(c('menu', 'tags'), nrow(dat), replace=TRUE)

newdat <- data.frame(model.matrix(~0+.+Species*navigation, dat))
> head(newdat)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Speciessetosa
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2             1
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2             1
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2             1
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2             1
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2             1
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4             1
  Speciesversicolor Speciesvirginica navigationtags
1                 0                0              0
2                 0                0              1
3                 0                0              0
4                 0                0              0
5                 0                0              1
6                 0                0              0
  Speciesversicolor:navigationtags Speciesvirginica:navigationtags
1                                0                               0
2                                0                               0
3                                0                               0
4                                0                               0
5                                0                               0
6                                0                               0
```

If for some reason you don't want to drop the reference levels, you can use the `dummyVars` function in [caret](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

Just for another option, you can also use `paste`.

```
your_data$sex_navigation <- with(your_data, paste(sex, navigation, sep = "_"))
```

You can, of course, cast that as a factor by wrapping it in `factor()`. The major difference between this and the `interaction` approach is that `interaction` will create a factor where the levels include *all possible* interactions, regardless of whether or not they are present. The `factor(paste())` approach will only include levels that are present. I find that `interaction` is usually preferable, but every now and again `paste` is what I want.